# After loading main focus page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I need to know how I'm going to focus on making a page when the user opens the page.

Have tried using `SP.SOP.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` and it does not work. After the DelayLoaded run it back as it was.

I'm trying this:

```
SP.SOP.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    $("body").attr('class',"ms-fullscreenmode");
    $("#fullscreenmode").css("display", "none");
    $("#exitfullscreenmode").css("display", "");
}, "sp.js");
```

Still does not work. After a few seconds it returns to normal.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Brother, if you want to come put pointless comment will not mess up. I just want to open a window already maximized.

Comment: Your question do lack a lot of information regarding what you are trying to accomplish, like is this in a modal or are are you trying to simulate a click on the "Focus on content" button?

Comment: Therefore, I am trying to simulate a click on Content Focus, but after clicking it back to normal, I want to click the first place. Like it was already opening a Focus Content

Comment: I'm not trying to make pointless comments, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve, like something is being lost in translation. I'm trying to get more clarity so we can assist you with your problem.

Comment: I'm from Brazil

Comment: I want to open the page so automatically:
http://spasipe.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/28.png?w=893

with focus

Answer (score 0):

I also don't fully understand, but it seems you want to do jQuery stuff after the page is loaded... You should use the jQuery's ready command not SharePoints executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded command.

```
$(function(){
    $("body").attr('class',"ms-fullscreenmode");
    $("#fullscreenmode").css("display", "none");
    $("#exitfullscreenmode").css("display", "");
});
```

On another note, I wouldn't edit sytles via jQuery if possible... It seems you can do this via css.

Comment: Does not work, nor in $(document).ready